# How to label only house number in python?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.1, labeling

I have parcel data that has the site address field as ex. 123 First Avenue.

I only want to label the house numbers on the map, so 123 in the example.

How can I do this using the label expression in ArcMap 10.1?

Comment: Do you ever have something like 123A or 678B or is that just a UK thing?. If so, you could extend the regex in the answer that this question is a duplicate of to handle that too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hacked this from the ESRI [Building label expressions](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s800000027000000) help page.  The general idea here is to use `.split()` to split the string at the spaces and then extract the first item in that last.

```
def convertLabel([NAME]):
  S = [NAME]
  S = S.split(" ")[0]
  return S
```

Comment: You could shorten the code in the function to just a return statement:

return [NAME].split(' ')[0]

although personally, I'd use a variable as the function argument, not the actual field name:

def convertLabel(nm):
    return nm.split(' ')[0]

Answer (score 2):

Provided the address field is holding string values with consistent order and formatting like "123 First Avenue" you could set the Label Expression Parser to Python and do something like this:

```
[SiteAddress].split(' ')[0]
```

This should split the complete address string into a list of strings by each space character in the string, and then return the very first element of the resulting list:

`[SiteAddress].split(' ')` -> returns a list like `['123', 'First', 'Avenue']`

indexing the [0] first element out of this list returns just the '123' for your label.

Best Luck with this.

Comment: for whatever reason this returns no values

Comment: Do you have a space between the quote marks?. Also, using this directly in Field Calculator probably needs exclamation marks around the field name, not brackets - !SiteAddress!, not [SiteAddress]. Make sure the parser is set to Python. VB is the default.